# Is it possible to get a regex for this?

Tags: regex, perl

I am trying to match a regex like this:

`[AB]{2}(...)[AB]{2}` where .... is a string of length 1 to 10 but must contain at least one X. Also, since there can be multiple such matches in the string, it must find all possible matches. For example, in the string `ABXBBDCXSBA` it should find both `ABXBB` and `BBDCXSBA`.

Is this possible?
Thanks,
CR.

Comment: Yes, that's very possible. What problem are you having? Some example input/output might help.

Comment: Why `ABXBBDCXSBA` isn't a result?

Comment: @Casimir et Hippolyte, Looks like they don't want any of the "delimiter" between the delimiters.

Comment: Maybe the example I gave was a little contrived. I was looking for the shortest matches I could find. It's just that the delimiters are allowed to overlap, but I am not looking for longer matches provided the shorter matches are good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with this pattern:

```
(?=([AB]{2}(?=[^ABX]*(?:[AB][^ABX]+)*[AB]?X).{1,10}?[AB]{2}))
```

details:

```
(?=(      # a capture group in a lookahead to get overlapped results
  [AB]{2} # starting delimiter
  # a lookahead that checks if there is an X before the ending delimiter
  (?=[^ABX]*(?:[AB][^ABX]+)*[AB]?X)
  .{1,10}? # less than 10 characters before the first ending delimiter
  [AB]{2}  # the ending delimiter
))
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/bE7oA6/1)

Comment: Thank you. This was most useful in understanding lookaheads too.

Comment: @CraniumRat, Since this answer gives the same results as mine, and you said mine is incorrect, then this answer is incorrect too.

Answer (score 1):

*[It's my understanding that `AA`, `AB`, `BA` and `BB` are not allowed within a match except as the delimiters.]*

For now, let's ignore the fact that the matches overlap.

Even then, this is actually very hard to do with regex. I suggest you initially ignore the restriction to have an `X`, then filter out the results without an `X`.

```
my @matches = grep /X/, /
    [AB]{2}
    [^AB] (?: [AB](?![AB]) | [^AB] ){0,9}
    [AB]{2}
/xg;
```

But we still have to address the overlapping problem. To do so, I suggest a lookahead.

```
my @matches;
while (/
    (
       [AB]{2}
       [^AB] (?: [AB](?![AB]) | [^AB] ){0,9}
    )
    (?=
       ( [AB]{2} )
    )
/xg) {
   my $match = $1 . $2;
   push @matches, $match if $match =~ /X/;
}
```

or

```
my @matches = grep /X/, /
    (?=
       (
          [AB]{2}
          [^AB] (?: [AB](?![AB]) | [^AB] ){0,9}
          [AB]{2}
       )
    )
/xg;
```

Comment: Unfortunately, they are not just delimiters, they can be present in the [A-Z] section in the middle.

Comment: @CraniumRat , Then why isn't `ABXBBDCXSBA` a valid answer for the example you gave? And what should `AAYYYAAXXXAA` give?

Answer (score 0):

i think this is what are you looking for

```
(?=([AB]{2}.{1,10}[AB]{2}))(?=.+X.+)
```

the (?= expr1)(?=expr2) is a sort of and. it first checks the expr1 , than if it maches it checks the expr2 In our case expr2 checks if the string contains at least one X and expr1 checks if the string has the right length and the rigth beginning and ending.

EDIT:
the correct regex is this:

```
(?=([AB]{2}.{1,10}[AB]{2}))(?=[AB]{2}.+X.+[AB]{2})
```

with the first regex the X could be used everywhere not only in the middle!

Comment: With this pattern, the X can be outside the delimiters. example: `AB1234567890BBX`

Comment: Yes, but the question (that hasn't already an answer) remains: are delimiters (i.e. `[AB]{2}`) allowed in the ten or less characters? And with your new pattern, there is no proof that the X is not the 14th or 20th character and that the ending delimiters in your lookaheads are the same.

Comment: Fails to handle `AAYYYAAXXXAA`.

Comment: i've assumed that (...)  is a string long at least 10 character with at least one X (that is what he has written). AYYYAAXXXAA is a match, isn't it?

Comment: Forget my example, it doesn't even work for the one example the OP gave.